# Many SQL DML statements in one transaction with cx_Oracle in python

Tags: sql, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I have 6 delete statements (that need to be executed in order) and then 8 merge statements. I would like them to all be in transaction--so the end user will never see data part of the way through the "update" process, e.g. data from tables that have had rows deleted but not yet merged.

How can I do this python and cx_Oracle?

```
    with cx_Oracle.connect("{u}/{p}@{db}".format(u=creds["user"], p=creds["password"], db=creds["server"])) \
        as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # ?
```

Python 2.7

cx_Oracle 5.1.2

Comment: Old way: write a stored procedure in Oracle, call stored procedure (passing arguments)

Comment: Great! Thanks, I was wondering if that was the way to go. I also noticed that it will work with cursor.execute() if I do: "begin... DML stuff... end;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call cursor.execute() for each of the 6 delete statements and then call cursor.execute() for each of the 8 merge statements followed by a call to connection.commit(). Until the commit is performed no other users will see the data changes. If your database is remote, however, you way with to use PL/SQL to avoid making 15 round-trips (1 for each call to cursor.execute() and 1 for the final call to connection.commit()).

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how the commit is done by cx_oracle, because even if I do not call commit() after the execute the DB is still modified. Also, connection.autocommit = 0. So, I don't get why it is committing.

Comment: If you use the with clause, that will automatically commit when the with block completes successfully (if it fails for some reason it will roll back). That is being changed for cx_Oracle 7. See here for more information: http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.__exit__.